# Remove density axis text in ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I am trying to remove axis text for the density plots within ggpairs. So, for this example, I hope to remove the text in the purple boxes:

[image]

I believe that to remove the y-axis text in the top left plot, I may need to make changes to the function printed in the third (last) line of this code:

```
library(GGally)
ps <- ggpairs(diamonds[,c(5,6,7)], upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size = 4))) + theme_gray()
attributes(ps[["plots"]][[1]]$fn)["fn"]
```

I am hoping to update this function in the ps object possibly into something like the following:

```
function (data, mapping, ..., rescale = FALSE) 
{
    mapping <- mapping_color_to_fill(mapping)
    p <- ggplot(data, mapping) + scale_y_continuous()
    if (identical(rescale, TRUE)) {
        p <- p + stat_density(aes(y = ..scaled.. * diff(range(x, 
na.rm = TRUE)) + min(x, na.rm = TRUE)), position = "identity", geom = "line", ...) + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
    }
    else {
        p <- p + geom_density(...) + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
    }
    p
}
<bytecode: 0x10cbcbb00>
<environment: namespace:GGally>
```

where I simply added theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) to two parts of the function. I am just not sure how to update the function this way in the ps object. I am hoping to do something along the lines of:

```
attributes(ps[["plots"]][[1]]$fn)["fn"] <- attributes(ps[["plots"]][[1]]$fn)["fn"] + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

Except with more detail to where I add theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()).

Specific question: How can I update this function?
General question: If specific question may not be feasible, how may I remove the unwanted y-axis text in the top-left plot and the unwanted x-axis text in the bottom-right plot?

Thanks for sharing ideas!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I just came across it and thought it might be useful for future plotters.

I couldn't figure out how to alter your function, but it's easy enough to remove those axes. The ggpairs object stores the plots as elements of a matrix, so for those plots which contain axes (the ones on the left and bottom) you can manipulate them directly.

```
ps <- ggpairs(diamonds[,c(5,6,7)], upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size = 4))) 

ps[1,1] <- ps[1,1] + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
                           axis.ticks = element_blank())

ps[3,3] <- ps[3,3] + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                           axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Critically, the `theme_gray()` must be removed from the original layering, because it will override other theme choices you make.

[image: Here's what the code makes]

Comment: similarly adding `diag = list(continuous = function(...) ggally_densityDiag(...) + 
                                                theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank())))` avoids stepping through the diagonal entries